# Rollback Entity Framework 7 database scheme in ASP.NET 5-beta8

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

On ASP.NET 5 Beta 8. EF7

What is the dnx command to rollback to the point before you created the database with your initial migration?

Answer (score 4):

Due to EntityFramework design meeting, they decided to modify some commands...
[Design Meeting Notes July 23, 2015](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes---July-23,-2015#nugetdnx-commands)

You could try to specify migration name during `database update`

```
dnx ef database update 0
```

Comment: To get to the point *before* your initial migration, you use `dnx ef database update 0`. Zero is a magic number. ;-)